# Facebook tab application scripting

Tags: facebook, fbjs

I have a web application that I am trying to port to Facebook. The app uses a few external javascript files. So initially I wanted to create an iframe Facebook application. However, it turns out that you cannot use iframes when creating a tab application(which is a requirement). By tab application I mean placing your app on the profile page next to the wall, info, photos, ect. tabs.

Does any one know of a good tool to help convert my javascript to the FBJS scripting? Or better yet does anyone have a work around so that I can include my own javascript in this tabbed application?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding loading external js is disabled when the user first visits the tab page (the passive page). But, once a page loads and the user interacts with it in some way (ajax post, redirect) the page is "active" and you can run flash, javascript, etc...

Comment: Yea you are right. I have since finished this project. It ended up be a ton of inline javascript. 

But I also found a nice jQuery FBJS port called FBJQRY(i think), which made parts of the project a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ruby on Rails and Facebooker, I wrote a nice little tutorial on how to inline your javascript inside a profile tab while keeping your code DRY :

http://modelix.net/2010/03/javascript-inside-a-facebook-profile-tab/

Answer (score 0):

I thought you might find this interesting, how to add a Live Chat Tab to a Facebook page:

http://apps.svpn.com/live-chat-tab-for-facebook-pages/